# could anyone explain, why this error comes "DUPLICATE_VALUE:This price definition already exists in this price"

Tags: data-loader, data-migration

DUPLICATE_VALUE:This price definition already exists in this price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you data loading duplicate price values in a PriceBook/Price Book Entry for a particular Product.

This is standard salesforce functionality preventing same Price for a product under a PriceBook.

Try cloning a PriceBook entry and saving it without chanding the Price and you will see this issue.

Comment: so, you mean if I change the UnitPrice field of PriceBookentry, I'll be able to load the duplicate ones also?

Comment: Yes.. Please try loading!!!

Comment: You can't have the same product in the same price book in the same currency more than once.

Answer (score 2):

For each Product2/Pricebook2/CurrencyIsoCode combination, you are only allowed to load a single value. This restriction is in place so that users can have the correct price for a given product based on the price book. If you want to have different prices, you need to have different price books.